# Accessing the DOM in the Vue Mounted function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pickadate

How do I access an element from within the mounted function in a VueJS instance.

When I try the following, it tells me that the element is undefined. When I see the DOM it is there. Could this be a case where the element is not rendered before I try to reference it?

```
document.getElementsByName('transferDate_submit')[0].addEventListener("change",function(){});
```

Comment: Can you give more code? dom should be able to be referred in mounted function, see my sample: https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/qb7cr912/

Answer (score 1):

You get a `HTMLElement` instance when you call your Vue.js instance with `$el`. Check the [API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el).

**Example**

```
let allLinks = this.$el.querySelectorAll('a')
```

Alternatively, you could use a `ref`. This is a like a programmatic ID. Also check the [API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref).

**Example**

```
<!-- vm.$refs.p will be the DOM node -->
<p ref="p">hello</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use v-on:change or @change to bind your event listener so that you can avoid manipulating DOM element. Besides, Vue.js is to make you not to DOM as far as possible

Comment: The element is being dynamically generated by a JavaScript plugin I am using. I want to use the value from the input field that is generated but need to add a change event listener to do that

Comment: `var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {  },
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.el.getElementsByName('transferDate_submit'));

        function test() {
            console.log("This is a change event");
        }

        document.getElementsByName('transferDate_submit')[0].addEventListener("change", test.bind(this));
 
    } });`  

Removed data for confidentiality purposes

Comment: Well, I would like to make the element as a template, and bind the function to this element. I recommend vue-cli to construct your project :)